# Passing an MSMQ Queue handle through an AppDomain or Process boundary

Tags: .net, msmq, isolation

Using AppDomain or possibly Process isolation in a .NET application, I don't necessarily want to give the isolated environment the permissions necessary to create or even open MSMQ MessageQueues.  I also don't want to use the isolation channel to have to pass messages back and forth from the privileged host just to enact this as I believe performance would take a big hit.

Is there a way to create/open the MessageQueue in the host and then pass the open handle to the Isolation environment for use (without remoting)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want the other process not to certain privileged operations on MessageQueue I would suggest to abstract it completely rather than passing the handle to the other process as that be a leaky abstraction. Performance wont be a concern if you design proper interface between the 2 process to communicate with each other.

Comment: Thanks.  Fine, but is it possible?

Comment: I guess would not be possible across process as handle are process specific